# Tersus for Android

Tags: android

Does anybody have experience with Tersus for Android ? Is it useful and worth to try or to continue to develop GUI on standard way from Eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being the lead developer of Tersus, here's my advice:

- Android support in Tersus is new, and we're not aware of many people using it yet.  You'll  certainly hit rough edges, but we'll be there to help you and fix what's missing.
- To get good GUI results, you'll need to understand HTML & CSS.
- Trying to put my own bias aside, I would give Tersus a try if I weren't fluent in Java-based Android development, if I wanted to develop for multiple platforms, or if I saw value in using the same language for server side and client side development. Tersus currently supports iPhone and Android. Symbian & Blackberry supports are planned for the near future.